# Uncommon rows based on a column in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, merge

Suppose I have two dataframes:

```
d1 = {'col1':['a','b','c'],
    'col2':[1,2,3],
    'col3':[4,5,6]}
df1 = pd.DataFrame(d1)
  col1  col2  col3
0    a     1     4
1    b     2     5
2    c     3     6
```

and

```
d2 = {'col1':['a','b']}
df2 = pd.DataFrame(d2)
  col1
0    a
1    b
```

I want to use the second `df` as reference and drop those rows that exist in `df2` from `df1`, so the result would be

```
  col1  col2  col3
0    c     3     6
```

I tried:

```
df2.merge(df1, how='left', on='col1')
```

but this gives me the following:

```
  col1  col2  col3
0    a     1     4
1    b     2     5
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`Series.isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html) with inverted mask by `~` in [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing), working well if need test only one column:

```
df = df1[~df1['col1'].isin(df2['col1'])]
print (df)
  col1  col2  col3
2    c     3     6
```

If need test 2 or more columns use [`DataFrame.merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) with `indicator` parameter and then test in if column is not `both`:

```
df = df2.merge(df1, how='outer', on='col1', indicator=True)
df = df[df.pop('_merge').ne('both')]
print (df)
  col1  col2  col3
2    c     3     6
```